# HTML-Pure html accordion collapse others

Tags: html, css

I need a negation pseudo-class to collapse the expanded content when .content [type=checkbox]:checked. How to say collapse all lists except clicked? Is it possible without javascript?

HTML:

```
<div class="accordion vertical">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-1" name="checkbox-accordion" />
            <label for="checkbox-1">Title&nbsp;One</label>
            <div class="content">
                <h3></h3>
                <p></p>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-2" name="checkbox-accordion" />
            <label for="checkbox-2">Title&nbsp;Two</label>
            <div class="content">
                <h3></h3>
                <p></p>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-3" name="checkbox-accordion" />
            <label for="checkbox-3">Title&nbsp;Three</label>
            <div class="content">
                <h3></h3>
                <p></p>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-4" name="checkbox-accordion" />
            <label for="checkbox-4">Title&nbsp;Four</label>
            <div class="content">
                <h3></h3>
                <p></p>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.accordion {
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
    margin:0 auto;
    font-size:14px;
    border:1px solid #542437;
    border-radius:10px;
    width:600px;
    padding:10px;
    background:#fff;
}
.accordion ul {
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;    
}
.accordion li {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.accordion [type=radio], .accordion [type=checkbox] {
    display:none;
}
.accordion label {
    display:block;
    font-size:16px;
    line-height:16px;
    background:#D95B43;
    border:1px solid #542437;
    color:#542437;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
    font-weight:700;
    cursor:pointer;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
.accordion ul li label:hover, .accordion [type=radio]:checked ~ label, .accordion [type=checkbox]:checked ~ label {
    background:#C02942;
    color:#FFF;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5)
}
.accordion .content {
    padding:0 10px;
    overflow:hidden;
    border:1px solid #fff;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease-out;
}
.accordion p {
    color:#333;
    margin:0 0 10px;
}
.accordion h3 {
    color:#542437;
    padding:0;
    margin:10px 0;
}
.vertical ul li {
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:0 0 1px;
}
.vertical ul li label {
    padding:10px;
}
.vertical [type=radio]:checked ~ label, .vertical [type=checkbox]:checked ~ label {
    border-bottom:0;
}
.vertical ul li label:hover {
    border:1px solid #542437;
}
.vertical ul li .content {
    height:0px;
    border-top:0;
    transition: all .5s ease-out;
}
.vertical [type=checkbox]:checked ~ label ~ .content {
    height:300px;
    border:1px solid #542437;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Yn4LS/

Comment: Tried [`:not`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not)?

Comment: Not possible with `checkbox:checked` and ONLY css/html. It IS possible using `radio:checked`

Comment: @ddenhartog I couldn't managed it. Can you modifiy my fiddle, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is actually simple easy to implement, see this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yn4LS/1/)

All I did was replace (in your HTML) the word "checkbox" with "radio" and then made ONE small edit to you CSS:

This is the last item in your CSS, and this needed to be "radio," not "checkbox"

```
.vertical [type=radio]:checked ~ label ~ .content {
    height:300px;
    border:1px solid #542437;
}
```

Comment: actually i tried that but you can't collapse all making this way.

Comment: lol. You want to have multiple accordions open and then have them all close upon the click of another Input?  Not possible using checkbox/radio and JUST html/css

Comment: No, If I want to expand one, then collapse other(s) if any expanded.
If I click an expanded one, then collapse that one. What I ment by "collapse all" was just a one state where all are collapsed.

Comment: The functionality you want requires more than just HTML/CSS (i.e. JavaScript).

Comment: I'll work on this, thanks.
[link](http://cssdeck.com/labs/content-accordion-in-pure-css3)

Comment: @Lite, thanks!  My JSFiddle does exactly what the link you provided does :)  If you want some help with the JavaScript let me know and I can help you.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I just realized that. It's very late here. How about to create a toggle class?